# A fire pales in comparison to how brightly I burn

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> More deadly than a gun,
> As fiery as the sun.
>
> Looking to escape me?
> Instead, breathe and be free.
>
> Control me or be aware,
> Else I lead you to despair.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> **WRATH** (one of the seven sins, akin to anger)

More deadly than a gun,

> Anger/rage/wrath can cause as much harm as a weapon, to both oneself, uninvolved third parties, and the target

As fiery as the sun.

> The popular phrase 'incandescent with rage'

Looking to escape me?
Instead, breathe and be free.

> The old adage of 'count to 10 before speaking, when angry'

Control me or be aware,
Else I lead you to despair.

> Keep your anger in check, else it will be the ruin of you

Hints:

> Title also refers to the how anger/wrath simmers and burns inside
>  First letter of each line spells out malice, another negative emotion

Comment: It could also possibly be rot13(ungerq), with very similar reasoning.

Comment: I mean, this wasn't the answer that I was looking for but it's so close to it, that I might just accept it anyway. (Especially since their wikipedia pages literally redirect to each other...)

Comment: Is it rot13(jengu) @Joe-You-Know ?

Comment: Yes it is, that is the correct answer.

Comment: Okie - updated the answer accordingly. Like you said, they're pretty much synonymous, although what you had in mind is a nicer and more "poetic" phrase (poetic implying a nice phrase, not limited to just poetry, what with seven sins, and all that).

Comment: It's the reason why I wrote the riddle with six lines, in reference to the other six, and the secret clue was supposed to be the seventh.